# Post count doesn't match number of posts shown in list in admin

Tags: posts, wp-admin

Please check below screenshot and let me know how is this possible.

If I am logged in blog page shows 3 posts on page, if logged out then it shows 4 posts

[image: Post counts]

Comment: Do you have something in the trash?

Comment: Trash would be listed then across the top next to published.

Comment: @TonyDjukic trash was empty , I removed post extra from DB

Comment: Sorry, my response was to Milosh N. but I forgot to mention.